# Is there any callback method in twitter using fabric in android after sharing the post?

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

I have used the following code to post the tweet in twitter,for the custom login button

```
File file = captureScreen();
TweetComposer.Builder builder = new TweetComposer.Builder(getActivity())
.text("just setting up my Fabric.")
.image(Uri.fromFile(file));
builder.show();
```

sharing the post with image is working fine, is there any call back method to show alert to user in success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below ->

```
Intent i = new TweetComposer.Builder(this)
                    .text(content)
                    .url(new URL(url))
                    .createIntent();
            startActivityForResult(i, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_TWITTER);

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE_TWITTER) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // do your stuff
            }
        }
    }
```